# Force browser to use only mobile data regardless of WiFi is connected?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data

Is it possible to force any Android internet browser to use only mobile data regardless of whether WiFi is connected or not?

My situation: I have a tablet with Android 5.0.1 and mobile data enabled. I have also a little mobile printer - Canon Pixma IP110. I have to travel and print invoices for my customers anywhere. I am connecting to the printer's access point (the internet is not available of course) but I need to keep the web application open where I print the invoices from, that's why I need force my browser to use only mobile data and not use the printer's access point.

Answer (score 1):

Simply **NO**

Because it is not a feature comes with the browser.

It is a general feature.

**When the device is connected to Wi-Fi, the device automatically disconnect from mobile data even if the data is turned on**